# MFC logo in a MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC application. When the application is launched, I see it is represented on the taskbar using the MFC logo. Also, the application Window Menu Bar has the MFC icon.
[image]
[image]

How can I replace these with custom made logos?

Comment: By making your own? Go into the VisualStudio resource editor and edit the icons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The icons are in the .ico file that is part of your project. Usually in the /res directory. You can edit them or replace them with files you generate.

Comment: No, there are some standard sizes for Windows icons. You can look up and read about icon sizes in MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

The icon file is stored with your project files. 
Go to `<Projects Folder>\SOLUTIONNAME\PROJECTNAME\res`. When you locate this folder, there should be a PROJECTNAME.ico file. rename the ico file you created to `PROJECTNAME.ico`. Next time you build your project, the MFC icon should be replaced with your custom icon.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going to [this](https://icon-icons.com/) site mostly because it does not require any registration and its 100% free.

You can then fine a suitable icon for your program bu searching keywords.

Then select the .ICO type and download.
Copy the .ico file to your “res” folder.

Then delete the .ico file and rename the downloaded file to .ico.